# Is this a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, histogram

I have done some processing to my original data. Before the processing I had a nice histogram with a bell shape. Now it still looks like a bell shape to me if I would slice off the first half and stick it to the end. But I'm not quite sure what happened here. Is this still a normal distribution? Or else, what kind of distribution is it? For my task (motion recognition) I am supposed to use normally distributed data and I'm not sure whether I can use the data if the distribution looks like this. Also, I think that if I have a normal distribution at the beginning, the data should still be normally distributed after I did my processing steps (because these only included normalization and subtracting the mean from each data point and then normalizing again).

[image]

I don't know much about distributions, so if you have any tips for me where I could read about that I'd be very happy, I couldn't find any information elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Kaly.  I'm sure you will get some good answers shortly to help you characterize these data, but in the meantime you might consider explaining *why* you want a name for the distribution.  How will that help advance your analysis?  Perhaps you should consider backing up a step and ask about how to work with your *original* data.

Comment: OK, you definitely have a problem because these data are about as far from Normal as they can be! What exactly do these data measure and what do you need to deduce from them? Could you supply a reference that explains why you are "supposed" to use Normally distributed data? (Motion data often are not Normal: see the examples at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2711 for instance.)

Comment: I recently found out that a Fisher's $z$-to-$r$ transformation of a normal distribution can start to look *a bit* like this, though of course the range is between 1 and -1 in that case. Also, no little bump in the middle, doesn't hug the outside walls of the plot as closely, and isn't quite so peaked. Just throwing that bit of trivia out there.

Comment: Please add how your data looked before the processing. What were your processing steps? There are several tests you can do, e.g.  Shapiro–Wilk test, the Pearson's chi-squared test and so on. But as the others say, what your histogram shows is definitely  not normally distributed.

Comment: The data appear truncated at -180 and +180 (i.e. 360 range) are these circular data or relating to angles measured in degrees? Or is this just a fluke with this sample?

Comment: Please describe what your data are, what processing you did, and what you plan to do that requires normality.

Comment: Looks Van Mises on the circle, as @GavinSimpson says.